# MeshLab: Inverting the value of one coordinate

Tags: meshlab

I'm doing archeological research where I have created 3D files in .ply format. They represent stone surfaces with grooves in negative relief. To make interpretation of the grooves easier, I now want to invert the grooves so that they become a positive relief instead. Can this be accomplished in MeshLab, and how?